# Wrong number of arguments Error when using * splat operator ruby

Tags: ruby, tdd

I am trying to use the splat operator for this method so I can pass multiple arguments as items from a menu.

```
def place_order *items
  @restaurant.receive_order(*items)
end
```

The test is as follows

```
 it "should be able to order multiple items from menu" do
   expect(user.place_order("burger", "chips")).to eq(:ordered)
 end
```

I get this error...

```
 2) User should be able to order multiple items from menu
 Failure/Error: expect(user.place_order("burger", "chips")).to eq(:ordered)
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

All the literature I have read mentions this as a way to soak up multiple arguments.

Just in case you were wondering about the other method called within place_order, this is how it looks...

```
def receive_order(*items)
  raise "Sorry not in stock" if @menu.key?(*items) == false
  @bill << items
  :ordered if @menu.fetch(*items) 
end
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `receive_order` method; it is passing multiple arguments to the `key?` method. The `key?` method takes only 1 argument.

```
@menu.key?(*items) # wrong
```

Change that to this:

```
# change the "all?" to "any?" if just one will do
# if you want to check existence of key:
items.all?{ |key| @menu.has_key?(key) } 
# if you want to check existence of value:
items.all?{ |val| @menu.key?(val) } # change if key can be `nil` or `false`
```

Also, in the same method you're calling `fetch` on a hash with multiple arguments and using the return value in a condition. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with this.

Here's how `fetch` behaves:

```
hash = {one: 1, two: 2}
hash.fetch(:one) #=> returns value of :one i.e. 1
hash.fetch(:two, :one) #=> seemingly returns first value found i.e. 2
hash.fetch(:three) #=> raises KeyError for absent keys
hash.fetch(:three, 3) #=> return the second passed argument if key is absent
hash.fetch(:three, 3, :four) #=> Error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
```

In your method, I believe you want to check for the existence of a key with `fetch`. If so, then you can implement something similar to the code I've shared in the beginning of this response.

Comment: I was hoping to fetch the values of the key and create a bill of some sort, now I realise it only returns the first value.

Comment: Just to expand on that, I was hoping to remove the values from my menu which were defined in the (*items) key? and then << that into an array. Currently searching for a suitable method. Thanks for your help!